# A single listener for multiple list items

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am using a `RecyclerView` for a list. Each layout item of the `RecyclerView` has a `Button`. This button is supposed to save some data(that which I bound to the view).

I thought that since the same button is in every view item, why not have a single static listener instance that I can bind to all the buttons. Because that would save some memory.

Now, a few points about the listener(`View.OnClickListener()`):

- It is stored as a static member of my `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and gets instantiated once when the data is being bound for the first item.
- The instance is created as an anonymous instance and inside a method( `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int position)`)
- Inside the `onClick(View v)` method of the listener, I access the data to be bound. This data is retrieved from the list of data objects stored as Adapter source using position provided in this method( `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int position)`).

Now, the **problem**:

When I click on button and check what item is going to be saved by the listener, I find that the first data entry in the `RecyclerView` is the one that gets saved corresponding to the clicks of any of the items of the `RecyclerView`.

I have no idea why this is happening. Can anybody find the cause of it?

Secondly, is this a good strategy to have a single listener for multiple list items?

---

***Note:*** I am unable to post the code for it. Sorry about that.

Comment: probably position causing issue either declare it final or use setTag/getTag of Button View to getting right position inside onClick method using  `v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle RecyclerView clicks is like this:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    viewHolder.actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            handleActionButtonClick(itemPosition);
        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}
```

It is simple and robust. Having single click listener for all the items is an extreme example of over optimisation. These few extra bytes will never matter and it will come with cost of extra boilerplate.

Comment: Yep, indeed it seems to be...I ended up following your approach a while after posting the question as it was getting complicated without any much payoff. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are getting the response based upon the first item of the `Recyclerview`, then to get the actual postion use `getAdapterPosition()` at `ViewHolder`class or `onBindView()` and `getTag()` might as well help to get the exact data
- Since `RecyclerView`(as its name suggest) recycles its child views, so there is no memory related issues.